# Differential evolution does not find global minimum

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, networkx

I am generating an Erdos-Renyi network and calculating its degree distribution. I know that it is close to [Poisson distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html), so I want to fit my empirical distribution to the theoretical one. To determine the parameters of the theoretical distribution, I use least squares with [differential evolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) minimizer from SciPy. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from scipy.stats import poisson, expon
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, differential_evolution
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
from scipy.integrate import quad
from functools import partial

def get_deg_distribution(G):
    deg_sequence = sorted([deg for _, deg in G.degree()], reverse=True)
    deg_distribution = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack(np.unique(deg_sequence, return_counts=True)),
                                    columns=['Degree', 'Count'])
    deg_distribution['Probability'] = deg_distribution['Count'] / deg_distribution['Count'].sum()

    deg_span = np.arange(deg_distribution['Degree'].min(), deg_distribution['Degree'].max() + 1)
    missing_degs = list(set(deg_span) - set(deg_distribution['Degree']))
    add_df = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=missing_degs, columns=['Count', 'Probability']).reset_index()
    add_df.columns = deg_distribution.columns
    deg_distribution = pd.concat([deg_distribution, add_df]).sort_values('Degree').reset_index(drop=True)

    return deg_distribution

G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(2500, 0.025, seed=42)
dist = get_deg_distribution(G)

xdata = list(dist['Degree'])
ydata = list(dist['Probability'])

def func(k, mu, loc):
    return poisson.pmf(k, mu, loc)

def param_func(params, ydata):
    return np.linalg.norm(partial(func, xdata)(*params) - ydata)**2

bounds = [(0, 100), (-5, 5)]

params_found = differential_evolution(param_func, bounds=bounds, args=(ydata,))['x']
```

Several mysteries occur with this code. Firslty, different runs of differential evolution yield different sets of parameters. This is not a problem per se because there could indeed be numerous global minima. However, *func(xdata, *params)* from these sets of parameters always yield zero, it is as if the method was minimizing *func* itself instead of its squared error *param_func*. Thirdly, *param_func* value on all of these parameter sets is exactly 0.03708384. Here is the catch - this is not a global minimum! Just take (65, 0) parameter set and it will give you reasonable approximation of the distribution, if you check the plots, and the error will be actually 0.002something. I have run the pipeline itself previously on other functions, try something like this:

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return a*x**2 + b

xdata = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
ydata = func(xdata, 1, 5)

def param_func(params, ydata):
    return np.linalg.norm(partial(func, xdata)(*params) - ydata)**2

bounds = [(-20, 20), (-20, 20)]

params_found = differential_evolution(param_func, bounds=bounds, args=(ydata,))['x']
```

It works perfectly fine, but on this specific case it fails completely and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your function is extremely flat, just try out calling `param_func` with varied arguments, e.g. add printing to see what differential evolution encounters.

```
params= [41.59913589  4.89105046] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [63.91254532 -0.92131526] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [68.37125624  0.89639623] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [45.14573252  4.65577815] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [22.67673743 -0.18044346] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [97.72482339 -2.55722856] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [52.78006606  2.19661847] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [93.83834497  1.06309298] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [77.03260669  3.93668517] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [71.58743947 -3.15837317] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [92.41338486 -1.26579432] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [12.5600005  -1.45394569] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [85.19070035 -0.4268145 ] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [59.43444477  1.35851078] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [60.46778441 -3.82879569] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [23.51634608 -3.59756272] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [38.7543976   3.12218973] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [28.67896624  2.45580586] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [55.4596277   4.19064059] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [76.25562633 -1.78696273] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [17.45482587  0.40538534] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [15.07905094 -2.72161755] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [1.95968808 2.81329829] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [81.5581296  -2.17837356] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [47.88669722 -4.446492  ] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [7.08142657 0.03370213] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [88.3735352   1.88745077] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [30.65315351 -4.81303647] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [6.32994012 3.63894112] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [36.36195255 -4.16279484] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [41.59913589  4.03415129] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [23.21663858  3.1233522 ] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [68.50852913  0.17748603] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [34.12052892 -1.33749366] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [17.043581    4.36269403] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [97.72482339  2.18998272] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [43.40457859  1.88110669] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [10.69430062  1.06309298] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [31.40159659 -2.21271748] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [32.22739184 -1.70684696] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [75.13605335  1.20226297] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [32.57892338  2.33051894] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [49.927827    0.71320109] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [25.80448259  4.92162336] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [6.29401507 4.19227187] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [54.33720709  4.17796811] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [54.79444146 -2.00878436] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [82.92651292  4.03998162] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [55.4596277   2.05457226] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [0.50126545 2.90680459] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [49.63974499 -1.81133026] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [18.43226804  3.58469356] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [55.990353   1.5163623] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [40.18236935 -1.11509064] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [58.62511485  1.60337965] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [7.08142657 0.91677437] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [50.96674056  2.33974317] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [71.71883967  2.55729519] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [88.58496221  2.4634768 ] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [46.03618557  3.4831179 ] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [41.59913589  4.03415129] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [41.5991359   4.03415129] param_func= 0.03708384
params= [41.59913589  4.0341513 ] param_func= 0.03708384
```

so from the perspective of any "reasonable" optimisation there is just nothing to be done, your function is constant. You can tweak the representation, stop conditions etc. but I would start with rethinking your problem/data statement.

In particular

```
partial(func, xdata)(*params)
```

is a vector of 0s for almost every single set of params, thus it probably does not do what you wanted it to do.

Lets add some plotting

```
param1 = np.linspace(bounds[0][0], bounds[0][1], 100)
param2 = np.linspace(bounds[1][0], bounds[1][1], 100)

xs = []
ys = []
vs = []
for p1 in param1:
    for p2 in param2:
        xs.append(p1)
        ys.append(p2)
        vs.append(param_func([p1, p2], ydata))

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("param 1")
plt.ylabel("param 2")
plt.scatter(xs, ys, c=vs, linewidth=0, alpha=0.5)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see the function is essentially completely flat, apart from edges. If we restrict second parameter to be on the edge, evolution finds the minimum as expected.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. I just did a quick check of the param_func aka error function values on the (0, 100) x (0, 100) space of parameters and here are the results.

https://imgur.com/a/yOfimOq

Black is that 0.03708384 value. Matrix is definitely 'sparse' but I'm not really sure if that can cause the method to fail to spectacularly.

Comment: this is a wrong plot. Plot your function wrt. your bounds, and you will see it is completely flat (see updated answer with the plot of what you are optimising over)

Comment: You can limit your second parameter to be in [5,5] or [-5,-5], as these are the only parts of the space where your function is not flat, and you will see the results are fine there.

Comment: I finally realized what was the problem - that second parameter of the function must be strictly integer, otherwise poisson.pmf fails and the rest follows.